Reading ayatul kursi after fardh namaz
(Abu Umamah reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Whoever recites the ‘verse of the Throne’ after every prescribed prayer, there will be nothing standing between him and entry into Paradise but his death.”
Do I have to know the meaning of ayatul kursi for this reward?

There's no reason to assume you do need to. But hey, there's no reason not to learn its meaning.
